# Set Alignment of cell in range based on text value in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to format the text to right align if the value in the cell equals "Total For The Month: ". I just need it to work for Worksheet1 in the workbook. If the value in cell C3 changes, I want the code to look through all the cells in column B and find any that equal "Total For The Month: " and right align it.  However, my code isn't working. When I modify cell C3, nothing happens.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("$B1:$B1000")

If Target.Address = "C3" Then

For Each WS In Worksheets  
    With WS
        For Each cel In SrchRng  
            If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Total For The Month: ") > 0 Then  
                cel.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight  
            End If  
        Next cel  
    End With  
    Next WS  

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When is your code being executed? Is it during WorkSheet Change, or at another time? Is your code even being executed at all?

Comment: Good question! I set it to execute during a change in cell C3. I’m assuming it is running when I update the contents of that cell. How can I check to make sure it’s running?  I’m not getting any errors. 
Maybe I can put it in a macro I can run manually first just to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know how to add a screenshot to a comment, I've decided to put this as an answer:

When you create a macro and you want to be sure it gets executed (or a certain line gets executed), you might add a breakpoint in the VBA editor, as you can see in this screenshot (just click in the left margin in order to add the breakpoint):

[image]

If the code is to be executed, the VBA editor pauzes there. If not, this piece of code is not executed.